# Table row jumps to next page on Microsoft Word for Mac (version 16.34/ 2020)

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, table-styles

I have inserted a table in Word, capturing quite a bit of info. I started with a blank table, in a new document and typed information as I went. I pasted information from one other document that I created (from scratch too). The table now spans over 17 pages.

My table starts out well, but as the pages progress, **each new row jumps to a new page.**
I am unable to select/ deselect 'allow row to break across pages' (Table properties). I have also tried paragraph formatting: 'keep lines together' and 'keep with next'. No page or other breaks are set.

When I select 'show/hide formatting marks' on the home tab: the merged cells (some of the initial cells, and three others further down in the table) show a small black box on the left. All cells have a circle with four lines at the end of each cell (I'm not sure what this symbol is called?).

This problem has happened to a number of previous documents as well: super frustrating! **How can I format the table/ document to continue the table rows, one row after another, on the same page** (only break across pages when there is no space left on the previous page)?

I am using Microsoft Word (version 16.34/ released 2020) on a MAC computer.

**I am eager to solve this problem and look forward to your insight.**

[PS request: Once I follow your advice, could you add how I may insert a break at a later stage if need be? ...just in case I need to know...]

Comment: Try this: Select all (Ctrl + A), open Paragraph properties and unselect Page break before on Line and Page Breaks tab.

Comment: Thank you Endrju, unfortunately this does not solve the problem. Thank you for trying :)

Comment: Please try to share some pics of what this looks like.  Or, even better, an example DOCX where this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jimtut (I didn't post a document/ photo as I understood it is not allowed). However, I was able to answer my question :)

Using a vertical text direction meant I couldn't select 'allow row to break across page' (Table properties). Hence, I **changed the text to horizontal**: left to right text only.

Hereafter I selected the table rows --> format paragraph --> lines and page breaks --> **selected 'keep lines together'**.

**Problem solved :)**

Thank you to everyone who helped!